# Chi-squared test on a data frame with wide data

Tags: r, chi-squared

I have data that looks like this:

```
ID  gamesAlone  gamesWithOthers  gamesRemotely  tvAlone  tvWithOthers  tvRemotely
1   1                                                    1
2                                1                       1
3                                1              1
4                                1              1
5                                1                       1
6                                1              1
7                                1              1
8               1                                        1
9   1                                                                   1
```

I would like code that can do the following two things:

First, transform this to a neat contingency table like this:

```
        Alone   WithOthers   Remotely
games   2       1            6
tv      4       4            1
```

Second, uses chi-squared to see if these activities (games v tv) differ in their social context.

This is code to generate the data frame:

```
data<-data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
             gamesAlone=c(1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1),
             gamesWithOthers=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA),
             gamesRemotely=c(NA,1,1,1,1,1,1,NA,NA),
             tvAlone=c(NA,NA,1,1,NA,1,1,NA,NA),
             tvWithOthers=c(1,1,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,1,NA),
             tvRemotely=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omit the first column *id* (`[-1]`), then take the sum of each column (`colSums`) while removing *NA* values (`na.rm=TRUE`), and put the resulting vector of length 6 into a matrix with 2 rows. If you want, you can also label the matrix dimensions accordingly (`dimnames` argument):

```
m <- matrix(
  colSums(data[-1], na.rm=T), 
  nrow=2, byrow=T, 
  dimnames = list(c("games", "tv"), c("alone", "withOthers", "remotely"))
)
m
#       alone withOthers remotely
# games     2          1        6
# tv        4          4        1
chisq.test(m)
# 
#   Pearson's Chi-squared test
# 
# data:  m
# X-squared = 6.0381, df = 2, p-value = 0.04885
```

Answer (score 1):

This will get you to the contingency table in the form that you gave. Suggestion: call your data frame `data1` instead of `data` to avoid confusion.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data1_table <- data1 %>% 
  gather(key, value, -ID) %>% 
  mutate(activity = ifelse(grepl("^tv", key), substring(key, 1, 2), substring(key, 1, 5)), 
         context = ifelse(grepl("^tv", key), substring(key, 3), substring(key, 6))) %>% 
  group_by(activity, context) %>% 
  summarise(n = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  spread(context, n)

# A tibble: 2 x 4
  activity Alone Remotely WithOthers
*    <chr> <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>
1    games     2        6          1
2       tv     4        1          4
```

For chi-squared: it depends what you want to compare and I would assume that your real data has higher counts. You could pipe the whole lot into `chisq.test` like this, but I don't think that's very informative:

```
data1_table %>%
  select(2:4) %>%
  chisq.test()
```

Comment: Simple and adequate solution.